# SELECTING with multiple WHERE conditions on same table

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am currently working on my sql query that looks like this

```
SELECT reference.agent_ID, reference.policy_ID, Count(reference.status_ID) AS [Quoted Motor Breakdown] , Sum(IIf([status_ID]=1,1,0)) AS sold
FROM reference
GROUP BY reference.agent_ID, reference.policy_ID
HAVING (((reference.policy_ID)=1));
```

So results show as below

```
Agent| Number of policies quoted for Motor breakdown|number of policies Motor breakdown sold
```

I would like to add more columns to the same table showing results for remaining type of policies :

```
reference.policy_ID=2 (Travel), 
reference.policy_ID=3 (Home Insurance)  next to one agent
```

example:
Mr Smith|Quoted Motor Breakdown| Sold| Quoted Motor Travel| Sold

I would also like to my query to show result=0 if there wos no quote for specific type of policy
Any advise would be much appreciated 
Thank you

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?  `Sum(IIf([status_ID]=1,1,0))` is non-standard SQL

Comment: @Magda . . . What is the `having` clause supposed to be doing?  Why are you aggregating by `reference.policy_ID`?

Answer (score 1):

I think you want conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT r.agent_ID,
       SUM(CASE WHEN r.policy_ID = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [Quoted Motor Breakdown],
       SUM(CASE WHEN r.policy_ID = 1 AND status_ID = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS sold,
       SUM(CASE WHEN r.policy_ID = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS NumTravel,
       SUM(CASE WHEN r.policy_ID = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS NumHomeInsurance
FROM reference r
GROUP BY r.agent_ID;
```

If you are using MS Access, then you'll need to use the non-standard `iif()` instead:

```
SELECT r.agent_ID,
       SUM(iif(r.policy_ID = 1, 1, 0)) AS [Quoted Motor Breakdown],
       SUM(iif(r.policy_ID = 1 AND status_ID = 1, 1, 0)) AS sold,
       SUM(iif(r.policy_ID = 2, 1, 0)) AS NumTravel,
       SUM(iif(r.policy_ID = 3, 1, 0)) AS NumHomeInsurance
FROM reference as r
GROUP BY r.agent_ID;
```

Comment: I don't think this is what he meant, his having clause if filtering the results of policy_id <> 1, so maybe correlated queries.

Comment: That is perfect , thank you for getting this issue resolved for me. I do work on Access Date base o n this occasion, so second solution works perfect